# Cannot get Makefile to use g++ instead of clang++ on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, g++, clang

I'm trying to compile a C++ library on Mac OS which compiles on Linux. (This is done via installing an R package via a Makevars file, see: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) On Linux, I see the following when I do `make`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c packagename.cpp -o packagename.o
g++ -std=c++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o packagename.so RcppExports.o packagename.o -llib1 -llib2 -llib3 -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/packagename/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
 * DONE (packagename)
```

When doing this with Mac OS, I notice it's using `clang++` instead, which appears to cause errors:

```
clang++  -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++  -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c packagename.cpp -o packagename.o
clang++  -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o packagename.so RcppExports.o packagename.o rcpp_hello_world.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/packagename/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘packagename’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/packagename/libs/packagename.so':

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

How do I specify in the Makefile to use `g++` and not `clang++`?

I have tried `CXX=g++` but this doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Wouldn't the errors generated by clang++ be more interesting?

Comment: And how come the Makefile uses a different compiler (with different parameters) on MacOS? Is this by any chance a *generated* Makefile, e.g. via autoconf or CMake? Or does the Makefile itself query the host system (which I doubt)?

Comment: I agree with DevSolar that you're probably trying to solve the wrong problem. However, that doesn't make the question inherently invalid so

Comment: Those build commands are _completely_ different. I think you'll have to look into this in more detail yourself first.

Comment: I am somewhat doubtful of clang++ being the culprit here; the compilation finishes without errors (by clang++), what fails is the loading of the shared object for testing purposes. That could have *many* reasons... does the file `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/packagename/libs/packagename.so` exist?

Comment: @DevSolar It appears so, yes. But this is re-created every time an R package is installed.

Comment: @DevSolar Here's the R package: https://github.com/d-lo/bambi, and here's the C library it uses extern against: https://github.com/d-lo/bamdb

Comment: @ShanZhengYang • Where did you install `g++`?  Did you use `brew`?  If so, check `brew --prefix gcc`, and make sure you are using that path... mine is `/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/g++-7`.

Comment: @Eljay It looks like I have both `/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/g++-7` and `/usr/local/opt/gcc`